# shared_ptr and COM object

Tags: c++11, gcc, com, shared-ptr

I have a COM object named factory (`IFactory`), and it has several methods like

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateDatabase(IDatabase** Result) = 0;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateProcessor(IProcessor** Result) = 0;
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateDocument(IDocument** Result) = 0;
.....
```

when I need create a `IDocument`, I need to do this:

```
IDocument* doc = nullptr;
factory->CreateDocument(&doc);
// some code here;
doc.Release();
```

So I want to create a common function to do this and generate a `shared_ptr`, so taht I do not need to release it manually.

I created a function like this:

```
template <typename T, typename K>
shared_ptr<T> create_new(K* p, HRESULT (K::*member)(T**)) {
    T* pointer = nullptr;
    (void)p->*member(&pointer);
    shared_ptr<T> result(pointer, [=](T* o) {
        o->Release();
    });
    return result;
}
```

This way, when I need create a new `IDocument` I just need:

```
auto doc = create_new(factory, &IFactory::CreateDocument);
// do not need release it manually
```

but this does not work, because the compiler needs more information to instantiate the template, so I use

```
auto doc = create_new(factory, (HRESULT (IFactory::*)(IDocument**))&IFactory::CreateDocument);
```

this way seems correct, but when I compile my code, the compiler stops at

```
(void)p->*member(&pointer);
```

and says:

```
must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'member (...)', e.g. '(... ->* member) (...)'

In instantiation of 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> create_new(K*, HRESULT (K::*)(T**)) [with T = IDocument; K = IFactory; HRESULT = long int]'
```

Could someone help me figure this out?

Compiler is MinGW-w64 GCC 4.8.5, but I tried GCC 5.3.0, with the same output.

Comment: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'member (...)', e.g. '(... ->* member) (...)'   THE STARS are REMOVED by stackoverflow :(

Comment: Use _backticks_ for code, not single quote marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, function calls bind tighter than member pointer dereference, so you need these parentheses:

```
(p->*member)(&pointer);
```

(Add cast to `void` as you prefer).

Second, you can improve your call syntax by specifying the argument for `T` explicitly; you should then not need the horrible cast:

```
auto doc = create_new<IDocument>(factory, &IFactory::CreateDocument);
```